# Link in message bird message never deliverd

Tags: ruby, api, sms, messagebird

Hi i would know how make my links work in my SMS with MessageBird

I send messages like this:

```
message = "Hello http://foxfinder.fr/documents/"+@document.id.to_s+".pdf"
            client = MessageBird::Client.new('KEY')
            client.message_create('FoxFinder', '+33647654886', message, :reference => 'Foobar')
```

When i dont add link the message is send and delivered but when i add a link with a '/' in it, the message is send but never delivered

UPDATE

I solve the problem, it was security check from messagebird, you need to contact support to allow links in your message

Comment: Have you checked the value of that `@document.id.to_s`?

Comment: Yes @SebastianPalma, i think the problem from them, i create a new account and it works with the test credits

Comment: You can use `byebug` before the message initialization and to check what's really the value of @document, or @document.id at that point, because aren't you seeing nothing in the logs?